# developing sites with Flex applications

Tags: apache-flex, flex3

I'm very new to Flex, and have studied a number of examples.  In every case there is a central mxml file, and possibly one or two other mxml files referenced from the main one.
This generates multiple panels onto one computer screen which achieve dynamic results with data binding.

What I don't yet grasp is how to create an ordinary site with flex. How do you achieve multiple pages to display to the user? What is the best way to link to another site page without starting up a new browser window?

This is basic stuff, but it is foxing me at the moment!

Answer (score 1):

you want to you view stacks.  Here is and example:
http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/flex-snippet-tutorial-view-stack-component